# Changing the way the database prints data

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on a program with SQLite3. Now I want to print data form the database. This is the code:

```
    c.execute("SELECT MAX(klantnummer) FROM klanten")
    uwklantnummer = c.fetchall()
```

If i print this I get like [(23,)], is it possible to change it so I get just 23?

Thanks!! (I'm quite new to programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fetchall` method is returning a result set as an array; you are printing that array, which is why it is formatted like that. To get your desired output, either retrieve the first element from the array, assuming it exists, and output that value, or iterate through the array and output the value of each element.

Answer (score -1):

```
   System.out.println("DAta :"+data.replaceAll("[(,)]","").replace("[","").replace("]",""));
```

*here data is String name*

Comment: This is fighting symptoms, not reasons. You should get the array member to print, not the whole array